# Cannot access react-bootstrap component <FormControl type="file"> using ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a situation where I need to use a ref to focus on an `react-bootstrap` `<FormControl type="file">` component.

For some reason, the ref is returning as 'null'?

Here is my code:

```
class component extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.focusInput = this.focusInput.bind(this);
    }

    focusInput() {
        console.log(this.test) // null
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FormControl
                type="file"
                inputRef={(test) => { this.test = test; }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I can't see any reason for this? If this doesn't work, what other way I could simulate a click on that input to open the file browser?

Thanks

Comment: where are you calling `focusInput`? in `componentWillMount`?

Comment: @DenniedeLange, nope - focusInput is actually being passed as a prop to a child component which is calling it via `this.props.focusInput()`

Comment: When is the childComponent calling `focusInput`? in `componentWillMount`?

Comment: @DenniedeLange nope, in an `onClick` event ```<Button onClick={() => this.props.focusInput()}>```

Comment: Any reason you're not calling `super()` in constructor? This is required for React

Comment: @DenniedeLange I am calling it, just didn't include it in the example for clarity

Comment: Ok. then your example doesn't reflect the problem you're having. Please see this example showing it does register: https://codesandbox.io/s/ywnnl5xzm1

Comment: @DenniedeLange I just re-created that example in my application and I have the same issue. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Ok, so it's a local problem (outdated libraries?) Can you reproduce it in a codesandbox?

Comment: @DenniedeLange it's ok, I just reformated my component so I don't need to use this structure. Thanks for the help, I'll upvote your comments!